# IllegalArgumentException The bucketName parameter must be specified. com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.rejectNull

Tags: hadoop, clojure, emr, cascalog

Running a Clojure `jar` on AWS-EMR cluster using `(hfs-textline)` and getting:

> IllegalArgumentException The bucketName parameter must be specified.  com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.rejectNull`.

Comment: Mark your answer as correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after many different tries the solution in this case was that 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY' and 'AWS_SECRET_KEY' values where wrong.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, it really is about bucketname. I mistyped `s3:///mkay4242`(3 slashes) instead of `s3://mkay4242`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried different solutions, but my region name is not correct.
Please select region name from given below

Previously I was using **US East(Ohio)** as a region, but after updating it to **us-east-2** in the properties file my code running successfully.

In application.properties file

> #aws.s3.region=US East(Ohio)

> aws.s3.region=us-east-2

```
public enum Regions {

GovCloud("us-gov-west-1", "AWS GovCloud (US)"),
US_GOV_EAST_1("us-gov-east-1", "AWS GovCloud (US-East)"),
US_EAST_1("us-east-1", "US East (N. Virginia)"),
US_EAST_2("us-east-2", "US East (Ohio)"),
US_WEST_1("us-west-1", "US West (N. California)"),
US_WEST_2("us-west-2", "US West (Oregon)"),
EU_WEST_1("eu-west-1", "EU (Ireland)"),
EU_WEST_2("eu-west-2", "EU (London)"),
EU_WEST_3("eu-west-3", "EU (Paris)"),
EU_CENTRAL_1("eu-central-1", "EU (Frankfurt)"),
EU_NORTH_1("eu-north-1", "EU (Stockholm)"),
EU_SOUTH_1("eu-south-1", "EU (Milan)"),
AP_EAST_1("ap-east-1", "Asia Pacific (Hong Kong)"),
AP_SOUTH_1("ap-south-1", "Asia Pacific (Mumbai)"),
AP_SOUTHEAST_1("ap-southeast-1", "Asia Pacific (Singapore)"),
AP_SOUTHEAST_2("ap-southeast-2", "Asia Pacific (Sydney)"),
AP_NORTHEAST_1("ap-northeast-1", "Asia Pacific (Tokyo)"),
AP_NORTHEAST_2("ap-northeast-2", "Asia Pacific (Seoul)"),
SA_EAST_1("sa-east-1", "South America (Sao Paulo)"),
CN_NORTH_1("cn-north-1", "China (Beijing)"),
CN_NORTHWEST_1("cn-northwest-1", "China (Ningxia)"),
CA_CENTRAL_1("ca-central-1", "Canada (Central)"),
ME_SOUTH_1("me-south-1", "Middle East (Bahrain)"),
AF_SOUTH_1("af-south-1", "Africa (Cape Town)")
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but check the params you send to AWS.

In my case, I was starting a rekognition task with a stored S3 video, I was sending:

```
Video: {
    S3Object: {
        Bucket: BUCKET_KEY,
        Name: filename //<- this was null
        }
}
```